# How to use Bluez .la file in other project?

Tags: linux, makefile, file-type, bluez

I have a CPP project, and i need to use some bluez's API(According to the example ***`bluez/tools/btgatt-server.c`***). In the **Makefile.tools** I found that:

```
tools_btgatt_server_SOURCES = tools/btgatt-server.c src/uuid-helper.c
tools_btgatt_server_LDADD = src/libshared-mainloop.la \
                            lib/libbluetooth-internal.la
```

So, if I want to use those API i need the three files **`uuid-helper.c libshared-mainloop.la libbluetooth-internal.la`**. I know .la file is only a text file, but i don't know how to "add/use" them to my project makefile. In other words, i want to know how to use the existing .la files in my project(**a simple Makefile example will be great**). Or is there any other way to call bluez's API?

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Those are just intermediate files. Copying or using them directly will not help, as it may depends on some more sources of Bluez. You need to use the GATT DBUS interfaces provided by Bluez for your application development. See the doc here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

Comment: @Parthiban Thanks for your advise. I've seen this part of the code: (https://github.com/Vudentz/BlueZ/blob/master/tools/gatt-service.c), but don't make sense. 1. If I want to use GATT, do I need to be very familiar with DBUS?  2. When using GATT, the header files is only glib.h, dbus.h and gdbus.h?  which library files are needed?  3. if i want to create a GATT server, what are the steps?

Comment: 1. Yes, if you are using DBUS interface. 2. Those are raw dbus implementations. What you will be interested is to use dbus bindings like gdbus. 3. I am not sure GATT/BLE. But it should be possible to create as external profile. You can find some gdbus gist here: https://gist.github.com/parthitce and its explanation here: https://www.linumiz.com. But I don't have examples for GATT yet!